# Why margins and mfx yield different results in R?

Tags: r, logit, probit, marginal-effect

When I run a simple logit regression between a binary variable $y$ over another binary variable $x$, the average marginal effects obtained by the function `logitmfx` (from `mfx` package) are different from those obtained by the function `margins` (from the eponymous package).

Because there is only one covariate ($x$), this discrepancy cannot be linked to a difference in concepts between average marginal effects (AME) and marginal effects at mean (MEM), as both coincide in this case.

Hence, what explains the gap?

Answer (score 2):

The reason lies in the types of the variables: `mfx` is insensitive to type, and treats a binary variable as a boolean, even if it is numeric; whereas `margins` treats differently factors or boolean from numerical variables. In particular, the marginal effect computed for binary numerical variables is the predicted output $y$ when the variable $x$ equals 1 minus the predicted $y$ when $x$ equals its *average*, instead of subtracting the predicted output at $x=0$, as in `mfx` or when $x$ is a factor or a boolean. Hence, if you change the types of $x$ and $y$ to logical (or factor), you should retrieve the results of `mfx`.

To conclude, the most intuitive and consistent definition is probably the one of `mfx`.